# Class 'Grpc\BaseStub' not found

Tags: php, grpc

Attempting to run PHP client code, generated by `protoc` from a bunch of `*.proto` files. The PHP code is running on a docker container with php7.3, and the GRPC extension is installed and enabled: `pecl/grpc is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.23.1`.

When the code runs, I get the following error: `Class 'Grpc\BaseStub' not found`.

The error is triggered by this line: `class ProductServiceClient extends \Grpc\BaseStub {`. This is a line from the autogenerated code, so it cannot be modified.

[edit]
Running `composer require grpc/grpc` resolved this issue; however, I now have `Class 'Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message' not found`.

[edit] 
Running `composer require google/protobuf` resolved the second issue.

Comment: This is resolved right?

Comment: @StanleyCheung oui, desole. I did not want to delete it, as I thought it might help others.

Comment: @chaseisabelle have you got the chance to fix it with the native extension instead of the composer package?

Comment: @chaseisabelle To solve the second issue you need to install protobuf extension

`pecl install -f protobuf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try add grpc lib:

```
composer require grpc/grpc
```

Comment: This is an around by using the pure-PHP version of gRPC instead of using the compiled version.

Based on the gRPC documentation, it's better to use the compile c version (PHP extension), as it much better in terms of performance.

Comment: @KhaledAttia, looks that it has changed for the newer versions - for at least grpc-1.37, there's a new note in docs `In addition to the grpc extension, you will need to install the grpc/grpc composer package as well` - https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/php#composer-package